# Lambda Python - Print Formatting Improvements

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have a lambda

This lambda goes off and reports on anyones access key older than a specific number of days.

import boto3, json, time, datetime, sys

```
sns = boto3.client('sns')
usernames = []
mylist = []

sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::999999999:role/role",
    RoleSessionName="AssumedRoleSession4"
)
credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']
client=boto3.client(
    'iam',
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
    )
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    users = client.list_users()
    for key in users['Users']:
        a = str(key['UserName'])
        usernames.append(a)
    for username in usernames:
        try:
            res = client.list_access_keys(UserName=username)  
            accesskeydate = res['AccessKeyMetadata'][0]['CreateDate'] 
            accesskeydate = accesskeydate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            currentdate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
            accesskeyd = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(accesskeydate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
            currentd = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(currentdate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
            active_days = (currentd - accesskeyd)/60/60/24 ### We get the data in seconds. converting it to days

            if 90 < active_days:
                a = str(username)
                c = int(int(round(active_days)))

                mylist.append(a)
                mylist.append(c)
        except:
                f = str('')

    print(mylist)
    finallist = ''.join(str(mylist))
    finallist = finallist

    sns_message = (finallist)
    response = sns.publish(
        TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:111111111:sns',
        Message= sns_message,
        Subject='Access Keys which need rotating',
    )
```

This returns

```
['David.Jim', 123, 'Dav.Jimmy', 469, 'David.Jimmy', 480, 'Jim.Dave', 103, 'Dave.Jimmy', 102, 'Jimmy.Dave', 179]
```

And with over 100 users with Access Keys older than 90 days, this becomes very difficult to review.  How can i improve my output?

Thanks
Nick

Comment: Loop over the list and print entry by entry

Answer (score 0):

Make real pairs and use `pprint` (stands for pretty print).

```
> import pprint
> mylist = ['David.Jim', 123, 'Dav.Jimmy', 469, 'David.Jimmy', 480, 'Jim.Dave', 103, 'Dave.Jimmy', 102, 'Jimmy.Dave', 179]
> pprint.pprint({username: active_days for username, active_days in zip(mylist[::2], mylist[1::2])}) 
{'Dav.Jimmy': 469,
 'Dave.Jimmy': 102,
 'David.Jim': 123,
 'David.Jimmy': 480,
 'Jim.Dave': 103,
 'Jimmy.Dave': 179}
```

Of course if you own the code it would be better to define `mylist` as a dictionnary from the beggining.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just format the output in your code?  For example:

```
mylist = ""
```

...

```
if 90 < active_days:
    a = str(username)
    c = int(int(round(active_days)))

    mylist += "User: " + a
    mylist += ", days: " + str(a)
    mylist += "\n"
```

And then use the string `mylist` to print and send.  There are other ways of doing this with a `format` method too but this should get you started.